# Vue.js, Url and Routing

Tags: url, vue.js, routes

I'm writing a Vue.js application. I don't know why it keeps appending '#' to every Url I type into the browser. Has anyone had a similar issue with Vue? For example, when I type 'localhost:8080/register' the browser changes it into 'localhost:8080/register#/'. The routing isn't working properly either. Does anyone know what may be causing the problem?

Comment: Read https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html

Answer (score 0):

In your route configuration, set the `mode` to **history**.

```
mode: "history"
```

like:

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  routes: [
    // ...
  ]
})
```